# Restoring TextView's Text with android:freezestext not working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to retain the text of TextView on screen rotation. Following is a snippet of my code.

SampleActivity.java

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static TextView mIntView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_layout.xml);

        mIntView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.int_view);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mIntView.setText(String.valueOf(1));
        }

        Log.d("Test", mIntView.getText().toString());
    }

}
```

sample_layout.xml

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/int_view"
     android:background="@drawable/circle"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="top|center"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
     android:textSize="25sp"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:textColor="@color/blue"
     android:freezesText="true"/>
```

android:freezesText="true" attribute should preserve the state of TextView. But still when I rotate my screen the Integer "1" is gone from the TextView. Am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can override onSaveInstanceState method and put all values you want to save. Get them back in onRestoreIntanceState method.

Save Value :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

      outState.putString(KEY, VALUE);
}
```

Restore Value :

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
if(savedInstanceState != null){

     String mString = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY);
     yourTextview.setText(mString); 

   }
 }
```

Comment: The android:freezestext="true" should take care of this but for some reason its not. With your approach, I'll have to save state of every text view that I have.

Comment: @VaibhavGupta : You can also store arrylist of values for different textview. Store textview's ID as key

Comment: @VaibhavGupta : I mean make bundle with key and value and store with savedInstanceState

Answer (score 0):

I am bit delayed in answering this, but I hope this helps.

No need of `savedInstanceState` when you are setting the textview property as `android:freezesText="true"`. It is as simple as that.

Just create a landscape variation of the `sample_layout.xml` file. Make sure, the `android:freezesText` is set to `true` in both the portrait and landscape variation of the `sample_layout.xml`.

[image: Create Landscape Variation]

Answer (score -2):

Whenever the device is rotated, the activity is destroyed and refreshed. So the Text is again refreshed.

To prevent this from happening, Use this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

If your app targets API level 13 or higher, you should set this config instead:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: This approach is generally not recommended, that's why I was looking for something else. Refer [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: My question is android restores the TextView's text if you set android:freezestext="true". Refer [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:freezesText). Why is it not doing this in my code.

Comment: Try `#setFreezesText(true);`

Comment: I am setting that property as true in layout xml.